# Looking for a pattern to vertically center images in a responsive amp-carousel

Tags: amp-html

I've got some content that's using `<amp-carousel type="slides" layout="responsive">` - the individual `<amp images>` are not all the same size.  The carousel correctly sizes to the largest image, I'd like to vertically center the smaller images.  Has anybody figure out the right CSS incantation to get that to happen within the AMP framework?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/8/). You need to wrap your image tags inside 2 div. For the `.outer-image-wrap`, set it to `display: table`, `height: 100%`, `width: 100%`. Then for the `.inner-image-wrap`, set it to `display: table-cell`; and `vertical-align: middle`.